# issues to read files from ZooKeeper using Kerberos secure authentication

Tags: hbase, kerberos, apache-zookeeper

I am using `Kerberos secure authentication` to read data from `ZooKeeper` from two linux servers. on one server connection to `ZooKeeper` getting lost intermittently and when I check for the error in logs I see several different error messages each time when I lost the connection. I have to restart my server each time to get connection to `ZooKeeper` again. On the other server it's perfectly working fine so not sure where to check on this issue. I have same code running on both server only difference is one is having Java 1.6 and the other with issue have 1.7. Will the java version is an issue?

Below is my code ...

```
 if (!UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled()) {
      try
      {
        throw new IOException("Security is not enabled in core-site.xml");
      }
      catch (IOException e1)
      {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    try
    {
      String uName = conf.get("kerbose.user");
      String ktabPath = conf.get("keytabPath");
      System.out.println("Logging in1" + uName);
      UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
      
      UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(uName, ktabPath);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the JAVA VAR I export ..

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/PATH TO FILE/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false"
```

Below is my hbase-site.xml ...

```
  <configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.env</name>
    <value>qat</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>kerbose.user</name>
    <value>USERNAME</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>keytabPath</name>
    <value>/PATHTO/flume.service.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
  <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.bucketcache.ioengine</name>
  <value>offheap</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.bucketcache.percentage.in.combinedcache</name>
  <value/>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.bucketcache.size</name>
  <value>10240</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.bulkload.staging.dir</name>
  <value>/apps/hbase/staging</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
  <value>10485760</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
  <value>35</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.abortonerror</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
  <value>604800000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter</name>
  <value>0.50</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
  <value>10737418240</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier</name>
  <value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size</name>
  <value>134217728</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.mslab.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hstore.compaction.max</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.hstore.compactionThreshold</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
  <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
  <value>60010</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hbase/VALUE</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.port</name>
  <value>60000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.region.server.rpc.scheduler.factory.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.ipc.PhoenixIndexRpcSchedulerFactory</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.lowerLimit</name>
  <value>0.38</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size</name>
  <value>0.4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit</name>
  <value>0.4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
  <value>60</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
  <value>60030</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hbase/VALUE</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.WALCellCodec</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.replication</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://SERVER/apps/hbase/data</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.controllerfactory.class</name>
  <value/>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
  <value>authentication</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
  <value>90000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.superuser</name>
  <value>hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/data0/hadoop/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>ZOOKEEPERSERVERS LIST</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.useMulti</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hfile.block.cache.size</name>
  <value>0.40</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions</name>
  <value> </value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>phoenix.query.timeoutMs</name>
  <value>60000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
  <value>30000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
  <value>/hbase-secure</value>
</property>
```

Please let me know where to check for this issue. Thanks.

## EDITED

Here is the error ...

```
2016-03-09 11:44:01,382 [http-bio-8080-exec-28] ERROR security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:USERNAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))]
2016-03-03 16:08:14,851 [http-bio-8080-exec-22] WARN  client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - Encountered problems when prefetch hbase:meta table: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:
Thu Mar 03 15:59:02 PST 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@db5183, java.io.IOException: Call to SERVERIP:60020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
2016-03-05 16:06:33,294 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:USERNAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))]
2016-03-06 00:00:23,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] WARN  security.UserGroupInformation  - Not attempting to re-login since the last re-login was attempted less than 600 seconds before.
2016-03-06 00:00:23,935 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] ERROR security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:USERNAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))]
2016-03-06 00:00:23,935 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] WARN  ipc.RpcClient  - Couldn't setup connection for USERNAME to hbase/SERVER
2016-03-06 00:00:23,936 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] ERROR security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:USERNAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for USERNAME to hbase/SERVER
Sun Mar 06 07:57:19 PST 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@3dd66a, java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for USERNAME to hbase/SERVER
Sun Mar 06 07:57:46 PST 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@3dd66a, java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for USERNAME to hbase/SERVER
2016-03-03 16:08:14,851 [http-bio-8080-exec-22] WARN  client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - Encountered problems when prefetch hbase:meta table: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:
Thu Mar 03 15:59:02 PST 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@db5183, java.io.IOException: Call to SERVERIP:60020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
2016-03-04 00:00:29,875 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] ERROR security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:USERNAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))]
2016-03-04 00:00:29,876 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] WARN  security.UserGroupInformation  - Not attempting to re-login since the last re-login was attempted less than 600 seconds before.
```

I stopped one server thinking may be zookeeper unable to handle more connections. But, wondering why the connection get lost everyday. I am still observing my application to find the Root Cause. Thanks

Comment: what are the error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry I was not sure which error to add as each day i get different error so I just added the couple of errors from different days.